# MySQL how to find common data in a few tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have three MySQL tables :

```
table1
list
a
b
c
d
e

table2
list
d
c
b
f
e

table3
list
f
e
c
b
a
```

what i want to get is

```
list
b
c
e
```

Because b,c,e are common in all the lists across these three tables.
I hope that don't have too many nested, because it may be more than three tables actually.

Comment: you can use inner join

Comment: Have u tried inner join
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list` varchar(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list` varchar(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list` varchar(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`list`) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`list`) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`list`) VALUES ('c');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`list`) VALUES ('d');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`list`) VALUES ('e');



INSERT INTO `table2` (`list`) VALUES ('d');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`list`) VALUES ('c');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`list`) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`list`) VALUES ('f');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`list`) VALUES ('e');


INSERT INTO `table3` (`list`) VALUES ('f');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`list`) VALUES ('e');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`list`) VALUES ('c');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`list`) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`list`) VALUES ('a');
```

Query:

```
Select t1.list
From table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.list = t2.list
INNER JOIN table3 as t3
on t2.list = t3.list
```

and you can also visit [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4aa5e4/1) for query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner join` as below

```
Select t1.list
From table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.list = t2.list
INNER JOIN table3 as t3
on t2.list = t3.list
```

Read more about [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)